# Is a new .war file uploaded to the webapps directory supposed to force tomcat restart?

Tags: tomcat, java

I am putting together a new build environment and when I upload a new .war file, Tomcat does not seem to be unwrapping it into a directory structure, or restarting.

Does there have to be some setting that needs to be set for this? I am using ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the autodeploy behavior, you'll want to find the `<Host>` block in your Tomcat config, and make sure the following is part of it: `unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"`

As long as those are set, it should automatically explode the .war file.  Keep in mind that this only applies to .war files placed in the webapps directory.

A service restart is not necessary for a redeploy, so you should not expect to see the Tomcat service restart itself.

Comment: I actually do have this setting:       <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"> in the tomcat/conf/server.xml - is there anywhere else I should set it?  Thanks!

Comment: @Genadinik Nope, that should do it.  As long as the .war is in the webapps directory, it should be deployed.  If it's not, maybe check the error log for issues with the deploy?